# Exception "System.AccessViolationException" occurs when opening 'OpenFileDialog' in VB.Net (VS 2012)

Tags: vb.net, access-violation, openfiledialog

I would really appreciate your help here. My application is as follows,

Operating System: Windows 7 64 Bit OS
Visual Studio: VS 2012
Application: VB.Net running on .Net framework 4

In my application, I have a button which calls my custom method ‘Select_Batch_File()’. Once this button is clicked it supposes to open the ‘OpenFileDialog’ to select particular file. This works fine on my machine with above configuration however; on some of my colleagues machine (with same configuration above) this does not work and fails without any exception. I have collected the thread dump from my colleague’s machine which is as follows,

======================

Log Name:      Application

Source:        .NET Runtime

Date:          3/18/2013 1:54:19 PM

Event ID:      1026

Task Category: None

Level:         Error

Keywords:      Classic

User:          N/A

Description:

Application: Visual AEEMS.exe

Framework Version: v4.0.30319

Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.

Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException

Stack:

at System.Windows.Forms.FileDialogNative+IFileDialog.Show(IntPtr)

at System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog.RunDialogVista(IntPtr)

at System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog.RunDialog(IntPtr)

at System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog.ShowDialog(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window)

===============

I followed a solution from MSDN forum wherein users were asked to uncheck the option in visual studio > Tools > Options > Debugging > ‘Suppress JIT optimization on module load (Managed only)’ but had no luck.

Here is my code

```
 Sub Select_Batch_File()
        Try

            Dim OpenFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog
            OpenFileDialog.AutoUpgradeEnabled = False
            Full_Path = "" : file_name = "" 
            OpenFileDialog.Multiselect = False

            Try
    <<Here I am getting exception>>    

                If (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
                    EMS_Dir = OpenFileDialog.FileName 'get the path
                    EMS_Dir = StrReverse(EMS_Dir) 'reverse the string
                    EMS_Dir = Mid(EMS_Dir, InStr(EMS_Dir, "\"), Len(EMS_Dir)) 'extract from the first slash
                    EMS_Dir = StrReverse(EMS_Dir) 'reverse it again
                    'file_name = OpenFileDialog.SafeFileName
                    file_name = OpenFileDialog.FileName
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Logger.LogInfo(ex) : MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try

        Catch ex As Exception
            Logger.LogInfo(ex) : MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Please advice.

Comment: It may not help with the question - but you should *definitely* familiarize yourself with the System.IO namespace - especially the System.IO.Path class.

Answer (score 0):

You will get an exception **if you set** the `AutoUpgradeEnabled` property.  Don't know why, but there it is.

Comment: I tried setting 'AutoUpgradeEmabled = false' but still the same error. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: **dont set it**.   .filler filler filler.  stoopid character limits.